# Retrieving information from a POST without forms in Django

Tags: python, django, apache, post, lamp

I'm developing something like an API (more like a communications server? Idk what to call it!) to receive data from a POST message from an external app. Basically this other app will encounter an error, then it sends an error ID in a post message to my API, then I send off an email to the affected account.

My question is how do I handle this in Django without any form of UI or forms? I want this to pretty much be done quietly in the background. At most a confirmation screen that the email is sent.

I'm using a LAMP stack with Python/Django instead of PHP.

Comment: Please show what you did so far.

Comment: I don't have terribly much relevant to the question as it's something I'm just not sure where to start with! And google just has examples of html forms it seems. I only have further methods taking (errorID) as a parameter, which would be passed from this problem.

Comment: i think what you should search for is `Django API POST request`

Comment: you should have all in `request` object which you get in view - [Request and response objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/)

Comment: Do you want to make this request from the users PC, so from inside your HTML code?

Comment: I want the user to send a request containing an ID code, my API will be sitting waiting on a message. On a separate device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Django view doesn't have to use a form. Everything that was POSTed is there in `request.POST` which you may access directly. (I commonly do this to see which of multiple submit buttons was clicked).

Forms are a good framework for validating the data that was POSTed, but you don't have to use their abilities to generate content for rendering. If the data is validated in the front-end, you can use the form validation framework to check against front-end coding errors and malicious POSTs not from your web page, and simply process the `cleaned_data` if `form.is_valid()` and do "Something went wrong" if it didn't (which you believe to be impossible, modulo front-end bugs or malice).